# running shell script using c programming

Tags: c, shell, system, exec

hello every one I want to ask that I am making a program in which i have to run shell script using c program. up till now i have separated the arguments. and i have searched that exec should be use to run shell scripts 
but i am totally confused as there are many variants of exec and by reading the man pages i am unable to find which is best suitable

Also in some exec function first arg is

> path

and some have

> pointer to file

what is the difference and what should i write in place of it.kindly guide me 
thanks

Comment: exec will replace your current program with the script. If you want your program to continue to run you should use `system` for synchronous execution and `fork` + `exec` for asynchronous execution.

Comment: Whether to choose execve or another function from the exec family depends on whether you want/need to use the path, pass in a list of environment variables, etc. If you don't, pick the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

Running a shell script from a C program is usually done using

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system (char *s);
```

where s is a pointer to the pathname of the script, e.g.

```
int rc = system ("/home/username/bin/somescript.sh");
```

If you need the stdout of the script, look at the `popen` man page.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
for ((i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++))\n\
do\n\
echo \"Count: $i\"\n\
done\n\
"

int main(void)
{
  puts("Will execute sh with the following script:");
  puts(SHELLSCRIPT);
  puts("Starting now:");
  system(SHELLSCRIPT);
  return 0;
}
```

Reference:
http://www.unix.com/programming/216190-putting-bash-script-c-program.html

Answer (score 0):

All `exec*` library functions are ultimately convenience wrappers over the `execve()` system call. Just use the one that you find more convenient.

The ones that end in `p` (`execlp()`, `execvp()`) use the `$PATH` environment variable to find the program to run. For the others you need to use the full path as the first argument.

The ones ending in `e` (`execle()`, `execve()`) allow you to define the environment (using the last argument). This way you avoid potential problems with `$PATH`, `$IFS` and other dangerous environment variables.

The ones wih an `v` in its name take an array to specify arguments to the program to run, while the ones with an `l` take the arguments to the program to run as variable arguments, ending in `(char *)NULL`. As an example, `execle()` is very convenient to construct a fixed invocation, while `execv*` allow for a number of arguments that varies programatically.